GnuTLS library produces TLS fatal alert on handshake for HTTPS connection
When I type gnutls-cli -p 443 stackoverflow.com on the Linux command line, the HTTPS connection is established successfully.
But my C program to establish the same type of connection does not work. What am I missing?
int main ()
{
    int Result_d, SocketFileDescriptor;
    gnutls_session_t GnutlsSession;
    struct sockaddr_in SockAddr;
    
    SocketFileDescriptor = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (SocketFileDescriptor == -1)
        return 0;
    
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_port = htons (443u);
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = (7u << 24u) | (32u << 16u) | (18u << 8u) | 104u; // `host -t a stackoverflow.com` outputs 104.18.32.7
    Result_d = connect (SocketFileDescriptor, (struct sockaddr *) & SockAddr, sizeof (SockAddr));
    if (Result_d != 0)
        return 0;
    
    Result_d = gnutls_init (& GnutlsSession, GNUTLS_CLIENT);
    if (Result_d != GNUTLS_E_SUCCESS)
        return 0;
    
    Result_d = gnutls_set_default_priority (GnutlsSession);
    if (Result_d != GNUTLS_E_SUCCESS)
        return 0;
    
    gnutls_transport_set_int (GnutlsSession, SocketFileDescriptor);
    
    Result_d = gnutls_server_name_set (GnutlsSession, GNUTLS_NAME_DNS, "stackoverflow.com", 17u);
    if (Result_d != GNUTLS_E_SUCCESS)
        return 0;
    
    Result_d = gnutls_handshake (GnutlsSession);
    if (Result_d != GNUTLS_E_SUCCESS)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "gnutls_handshake() returned: %s\n", gnutls_strerror (Result_d));
        return 0;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

The output is:
gnutls_handshake() returned: A TLS fatal alert has been received.

Use gnutls logging or capture the TLS handshake with Wireshark to see what your client sends to the server. Compare it with the handshake used by the gnutls-cli -p 443 stackoverflow.com command.
